# How can I measure phase shift in Multisim using a Tektronix oscilloscope?

Tags: multisim, phase-shift

I have to measure the phase shift between input and output of amplifiers.

Below is an example circuit with voltage charts (yellow is input, blue is output.)

How do I measure phase shift between them?

I could do it by looking at the charts but I heavily doubt that the teacher will accept it.

[image]

Comment: First turn down the input level so that the amplifier doesn't clip.

Comment: What do you mean by clipping?

Comment: If not from the chart by looking, what do you expect the teacher wants you to do? See if there is some phase shift measurement option in the scope. I would not be surprised if the DSO provided such a menu item.

Comment: @JRE: The circuit is a differentiator. The output is **supposed** to be a square wave!

Comment: The concept of "phase shift" would be easier to see if you use sine waves.

Comment: Don't you think you should ask the teacher what they **will** accept?

Comment: Ok.
@AJN "If not from the chart by looking, what do you expect the teacher wants you to do?" you got me here.
I have found another oscilloscope that has two "cursors" whith which I can measure the actual phase shift. So I considier the problem as solved

Comment: But anyway does anybody know what is maximal allowable voltage value for tektronix in multisim?
I am asking this because I have to set maximal possible amplitude of input signal that tektronix will work with.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use oscilloscope in A/B mode? If it is possible, you should get a oval-like lissajous figure. Then count

1. the distance between zero point and the leftest intersection with X=0
2. the linear distance between the most left and most right X pos.

The arcsin function of (1st distance / 2nd distance) will grant you the phase value in degrees.